# External USB monitor not working

Tags: 16.04, usb, multiple-monitors, external-monitor, displaylink

I recently bought an external monitor AOC E1659FWU.
In my possession I have a Dell Latitude E6420 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have downloaded the driver from

> http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu

And followed the instructions from

> http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu

My ubuntu machine does detect the monitor but there is no window on the device. Just black.
Supposedly it should be working now but -you guessed it- it doesn't.

There is probably no single solution for the problem. So what do you recommend me to try?

Comment: If your computer detected monitor, I think it's not fault from video driver, but may be some issue related to Monitor, because it is USB. [Look at this discussion at DisplayLink Forum](http://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?s=358a16a7b8a7cf6ac4ec701152e605fb&t=64893&page=2). As @dobey  suggested.

Comment: I would suggest contacting DisplayLink's support, as it is a proprietary driver not included in the Ubuntu distribution. You're more likely to find a solution on their forums or knowledgebase, than here.